# After updating Android App to lollipop it only shows a blank screen and actionbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been given some extremely old code, written by an intern quite a few years ago. The app had been working (mostly) fine up until lollipop, where it cannot be installed and if the OS was upgraded from a previous version it works only some of the time.
The app was relatively recently updated to change some details on our about page but has otherwise remained untouched.

I have updated android studio (1.2.1.1), used the SDK manager to ensure than the relevant tools are installed and used the code inspection tool to ensure all deprecated code is updated. I have set the target SDK to 21 and the minimum has been changed from 7 to 8 in order to resolve some compatibility issues between that and the newer code.

The app compiles and loads onto the device/emulators fine but after the splash screen with the app-logo fades out it just shows a blank white page with an action bar at the top.
The action bar should have an icon for a sliding menu drawer but that doesn't display.
The emulator loads up a keyboard which you can enter 3 lots of text into, so it sort of looks like it's correctly directing the user to the settings page (which needs 3 pieces of information) but not displaying the elements correctly.

I am unsure what my best course of action is now; **has anyone else had a similar problem or has any suggestion on how to proceed?**

I didn't want to spam upload the various views, classes and config files but I can certainly upload some of the content if needed.

Comment: Have you tried using Hierarchy Viewer to first check if the UI components are where they should be?

Comment: I'm getting issues trying to use that - I'll report back if I can get it to work with ViewServer.
I got DumpViewHeirarchy to work but I'm unsure how to use that information